# Getting Annotation Exception When Referencing a Composite Key

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping, hibernate-annotations

I'm getting org.hibernate.AnnotationException in Entities that looks like correct to me.

The detailed error is:

```
org.hibernate.AnnotationException: referencedColumnNames(COD_GRUPO_ATRACAO, COD_APLICACAO, COD_GRUPO_ATRACAO) of **.***.*****.***.******.******.AssociacaoGrupoAtracao.associacaoGrupoAtracao referencing **.***.*****.***.******.******.GrupoAtracaoAplicacao not mapped to a single property
```

Here is my two Entities:

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public abstract class BaseDomain implements Serializable {
    public final static String DOMAINS_PACKAGE = "**.***.*****.***.domain";
}

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@Entity
@IdClass(GrupoAtracaoAplicacaoPK.class)
@Table(name = "GRUPO_ATRACAO_APLICACAO")
public class GrupoAtracaoAplicacao extends BaseDomain {

   @Id
   @Column(name = "COD_APLICACAO")
   private Long codAplicacao;

   @Id
   @Column(name = "COD_GRUPO_ATRACAO")
   private Long codGrupoAtracao;

   [...]

   @OneToMany(targetEntity = AssociacaoGrupoAtracao.class)
   @JoinColumns( {
               @JoinColumn(name = "COD_GRUPO_ATRACAO_INFERIOR", referencedColumnName = "COD_GRUPO_ATRACAO", insertable = false, updatable = false),
               @JoinColumn(name = "COD_APLICACAO", referencedColumnName = "COD_APLICACAO", insertable = false, updatable = false),
               @JoinColumn(name = "COD_GRUPO_ATRACAO_SUPERIOR", referencedColumnName = "COD_GRUPO_ATRACAO", insertable = false, updatable = false) 
            })
    private List<AssociacaoGrupoAtracao> associacaoGrupoAtracao;

    [...]
}

public class GrupoAtracaoAplicacaoPK implements Serializable {

    @Column(name = "COD_APLICACAO")
    private Long codAplicacao;

    @Column(name = "COD_GRUPO_ATRACAO")
    private Long codGrupoAtracao;

    [...]
}

@NamedQuery(name = "metadado", query = "FROM AssociacaoGrupoAtracao AGA, GrupoAtracao AS GA, GrupoAtracaoAplicacao AS GAA  WHERE GAA.codGrupoAtracao = AGA.codGrupoAtracaoInferior AND GAA.codAplicacao = AGA.codAplicacao AND GA.codGrupoAtracao = GAA.codGrupoAtracao AND AGA.codAplicacao = ? AND GAA.codMetadadoGrupoAtracao = ? AND AGA.codGrupoAtracaoSuperior = 2 ORDER BY AGA.numOrdem, GA.nomGrupoAtracao ASC")
@Entity
@IdClass(AssociacaoGrupoAtracaoPK.class)
@Table(name = "ASSOCIACAO_GRUPO_ATRACAO")
public class AssociacaoGrupoAtracao extends BaseDomain {

   [...]

   @Id
   @Column(name = "COD_APLICACAO")
   public Long getCodAplicacao() {
       return this.codAplicacao;
   }

   public void setCodAplicacao(Long codAplicacao) {
       this.codAplicacao = codAplicacao;
   }

   @Id
   @Column(name = "COD_GRUPO_ATRACAO_INFERIOR")
   public Long getCodGrupoAtracaoInferior() {
      return this.codGrupoAtracaoInferior;
   }

   public void setCodGrupoAtracaoInferior(Long codGrupoAtracaoInferior) {
      this.codGrupoAtracaoInferior = codGrupoAtracaoInferior;
   }

   @Id
   @Column(name = "COD_GRUPO_ATRACAO_SUPERIOR")
   public Long getCodGrupoAtracaoSuperior() {
      return this.codGrupoAtracaoSuperior;
   }

   public void setCodGrupoAtracaoSuperior(Long codGrupoAtracaoSuperior) {
      this.codGrupoAtracaoSuperior = codGrupoAtracaoSuperior;
   }

   [...]
}

public class AssociacaoGrupoAtracaoPK implements Serializable {

[...]

   @Column(name = "COD_APLICACAO")
   public Long getCodAplicacao() {
      return codAplicacao;
   }

   public void setCodAplicacao(Long codAplicacao) {
      this.codAplicacao = codAplicacao;
   }

   @Column(name = "COD_GRUPO_ATRACAO_INFERIOR")
   public Long getCodGrupoAtracaoInferior() {
      return codGrupoAtracaoInferior;
   }

   public void setCodGrupoAtracaoInferior(Long codGrupoAtracaoInferior) {
      this.codGrupoAtracaoInferior = codGrupoAtracaoInferior;
   }

   @Column(name = "COD_GRUPO_ATRACAO_SUPERIOR")
   public Long getCodGrupoAtracaoSuperior() {
      return codGrupoAtracaoSuperior;
   }

   public void setCodGrupoAtracaoSuperior(Long codGrupoAtracaoSuperior) {
      this.codGrupoAtracaoSuperior = codGrupoAtracaoSuperior;
   }

   [...]
}
```

Any one can point me out what I'm doing wrong.
I'm facing this error when I deploy the project into JBoss EAP 6 with Hibernate 4 and Spring 4.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem comes because of you are indicating @IdClass(GrupoAtracaoAplicacaoPK.class) in the entity, plus, there are two attribute as @Id. In both entities you declare the columns COD_APLICACAO and COD_GRUPO_ATRACAO and hibernate gets confused.

Try take @Id out and add @Column(name = "COD_APLICACAO", insertable=false, updatable=false) in the GrupoAtracaoAplicacao entity.